# Having trouble rendering 2 images side-by-side the original images being altered

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt

I'm trying to create a program that can open two jpegs with the same dimensions, and create a new jpeg that has those two images placed side-by-side with no change to wither image.

The code that creates the new image is this:

```
public static Picture sumPicturesHorizontally(Picture left, Picture right) {

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
            left.getWidth() + right.getWidth(), 
            left.getHeight(), 
            left.getImage().getType());

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(left.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(right.getImage(), left.getWidth(), 0, null);

    Picture p = new Picture(newImage);
    return p;
}
```

(Picture just my a wrapper class that contains a BufferedImage and that image's dimensions)

For the most part, this works.  However, the image that's output isn't just the left and right images side-by-side, it seems that something is modifying the border between the left and right images.

I have a yellow square, and a red square; my source images are 1 constant color.  The sum image, however, has some artifacts around the new border that aren't in the original.  Here's a zoomed-in screenshot of what I'm talking about: 
[image]

If I zoom to the same level on my source images, I don't see the same artifacts on the edges. I'd like it to be just yellow to the edge, then just red.  There should'nt be different shades of yellow and red.  Is there some config to make it behave this way, or a different method of rendering?
Also, I don't normally work with graphics, is there a name for what this edge blending is called?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

your code is OK and have no problem

and your image without zoom also OK and have no artifacts

the only problem in the "zoom" level which you do

when you make the Zoom you will need to get additional pixel not in your original image

this pixel is calculated by algorithm , this algorithm used the neighbor pixels around the edge between the two color (the red and the yellow pixel) to calculate the new pixel in the zoomed image

---

see this image : it make a zoom for specific part , you can see like squares ,but in the original image you can see this is tiny pixel

[image]

---

Note: this is why when you buy a camera you need to ask about it's resolution , because when the resolution increase the image quality increase even if you make a zoom to this level.

---

**I used your code and this is the output :**

1- [image]

this is the two image without any zoom and have no artifact

2-[image]

this is the two image after make a zoom in , here i can see the artifact

Comment: When I view the sources 'original size', they're clearly 1 color.  However, when I view the output of my program, even at original size, I can see that there are rows of pixels that are different colors.  I just zoomed in to emphasize the issue but the issue is there when there's no zoom on the image.

Comment: see my edit ,  i used your code and it's OK , and your error show when i zoom it , so can you tell me the width and height for each image you use??

Comment: In the image that you have as 1, I see that there are rows of pixels in the yellow part of the image that have a reddish hue that weren't in the original image.  Its faint but its there.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on Windows 7 using JDK7. Post your SSCCE so we can see exactly how you tested this.

This is the SSCCE I used:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MergeImageSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public MergeImageSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        int size = 100;

        Image left = createImage(size, Color.YELLOW);
        Image right = createImage(size, Color.RED);
        Image merged = merge(left, right);

        add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon(left) ) );
        add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon(right) ) );
        add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon(merged) ) );
    }


    public static Image createImage(int size, Color color)
    {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor( color );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
        g.dispose();

        return image;
    }

    public static Image merge(Image left, Image right)
    {
        BufferedImage merged = new BufferedImage(
            left.getWidth(null) + right.getWidth(null), left.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) merged.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(left, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(right, left.getWidth(null), 0, null);

        return merged;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MergeImageSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new MergeImageSSCCE() );
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the internet:

```
System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail);

graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```